# My build time exceeds 8 hours - what to do?

Tags: tfsbuild, build-server

I recently made some changes to my build server to do post-build optimizations such as optimizing PNG and JPEG images, minifying JavaScript and CSS, and then deploying my full project to the production environment.

For JS optimization I am using UglifyJS on every JavaScript file in the website root. For PNG images I am using PNGCRUSH, which will brute-force the best optimization technique for every image (this is the one taking the longest time). For JPEG optimization I am using ImageMagick.

**In general, what I want to know is this: How do larger corporations avoid having long build/deployment times?**

I can live with 8 hours of build time, since my server only builds at saturdays, and at night. However, I can easily imagine this problem getting worse.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Add a flag to do the PNG conversion incrementally?

Comment: Maybe you should save the optimized files somewhere. The next time you check if the source file has changed and if it didn't you can use the 'old' optimized file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pngcrush without the -brute option runs about 15 times as fast as "pngcrush -brute" but achieves nearly the same compression.  The -brute option generally only squeezes the images a small fraction of a percent more, if any.